# Component Not Receiving Values from @Input() - Ionic 2

Tags: angular, input, ionic2, components

So I'm working on a communication app, and I want a collection of messages to be passed into the `twine-message` component from the `twine-messages` component. Below are the implementations of both files.

`twine-messages`:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
      selector: 'twine-messages',
      template: `
            <ion-content>
                  <twine-message *ngFor="let message of messages;"
                        name="{{message.name}}"
                        user="{{message.user}}"
                        type="{{message.type}}"
                        messages="{{message.messages}}"
                        time="{{message.time}}">
                  </twine-message>
            </ion-content>
      `
})

export class MessagesComponent {
      messages: any = [
            {
                  name: "Peter Parker",
                  user: "user5",
                  type: "twiner",
                  messages: [
                        "Hey guys! You both get 3 hours of sleep so I thought you might like each other's company!"
                  ],
                  time: "3:00pm"
            },
            {
                  name: "",
                  user: "user2",
                  type: "time",
                  messages: [],
                  time: "7:15pm"
            },
            {
                  name: "Vikki",
                  user: "user6",
                  type: "twinee",
                  messages: [
                        "Hi! How are ya?"
                  ],
                  time: "7:15pm"
            },
            {
                  name: "You",
                  user: "user2",
                  type: "user",
                  messages: [
                        "I'm great! So, how'd you meet Peter?"
                  ],
                  time: "7:16pm"
            }
      ];
      @ViewChild('searchbar') searchBar;

      ionViewDidLoad () {
            this.searchBar.setFocus();
      }
}
```

`twine-message`:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
      selector: 'twine-message',
      template: `
            <div class="center">
                  <img src="templates/{{user}}.png" alt="{{name}}"/>
                  <h3>{{name}}</h3>
                  <ion-card *ngFor="let message of messages">
                        <ion-grid>
                              <p>{{message}}</p>
                        </ion-grid>
                  </ion-card>
            </div>
      `
})

export class MessageComponent {
      @Input() public name: string;
      @Input() public user: string;
      @Input() public time: string;
      @Input() public type: string;
      @Input() public messages: any;
}
```

My issue is that when I run this code, the @Input() values are undefined. For instance, I receive this error when trying to load an image using the `user` variable: `GET http://localhost:8100/templates/.png 404 (Not Found)`. I scoured every single StackOverflow, GitHub, and Ionic 2 Support solution, and have had no luck. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: name, user, type, messages, and time should each be in brackets in your html template. Is this just a typo?

Comment: They are not supposed to be in brackets. It causes an interpolation error. `Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{message.name}}] in MessagesComponent@14:24` If you were to use brackets, you have to remove the templating braces from the variables, but this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Ah didn't notice the brackets, I don't think those are needed, I think you need something like this [user]="message.user"

Answer (score 0):

You should use property bindings

```
<twine-message *ngFor="let message of messages;"
                        [name]="message.name"
                        [user=]"message.user"
                        [type]="message.type"
                        [messages]="message.messages"
                        [time]="message.time">
</twine-message>
```

Comment: Already tried, but still no luck--it has the same effect. It's really strange because I use the same process to inject data into other components and it works fine there. Thanks for the answer, though.